# Is there any way to check that a file is opened by any stream in write mode in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, input, fstream

I have an issue at hand. Let me first describe my issue. I have a multithreaded application, and one thread has opened a file say abc.txt for writing using `fstream`. Another thread at same time opened it for reading using again `fstream`. Now while first thread is processing, second thread found the file empty, and unlinks it. First thread after processing at the end calls, flush method to write to the file.

This scenario is causing chaos for my application. Could anyone please suggest is there any way I can check in my second thread that whether the file is already opened by other stream for writing? Is there any bit set in file properties for the same and how to use that?

Note: My cluster system does not support flock.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your platform OS?

Comment: You can store that information and share it between the threads.

Comment: As molbdnilo says, use a lock/mutex

Comment: Maybe you should use some protection to access the file, e.g. `mutex`

Comment: OS used is Redhat 3.10.0-229.28.1.el7.x86_64.  I have thought of using the mutex. But it will seriously hit the performance of my system.

Comment: If your threads need to write to the file at that specific moment of computing then i don't think there is much to do. You just have to wait for the other threads to stop using the shared memory. If you can write some other time, implement something like a buffer where when you can't write to the file (because of the lock) you write to the buffer and periodically check and flush to the file. try_lock can be helpful